# Is there a module that makes the fields in the grid resizable by users?

Tags: angularjs, datatables

We are using this angularjs datatable module.
http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/

Is very nice and a lot of functionalities.

In the oficial docs and API there isn't support for resizable columns bust in our project we need it.

Does anyone know by chance an unofficial module or library that add such features?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by resizable, do you mean automatically size based on content, or a drag-drop style resizing?

Comment: I mean dragging the user for redim like in excel for example in order to widen columns for confortable reading

Answer (score 2):

The third party plugin [**colResize**](https://github.com/Silvacom/colResize) works with angular dataTables too. Simply include `dataTables.colResize.js` in your project and include the `Z` option in `withDom()`, example :

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withDOM('Zlfrtip')
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/UgTiUn94XWuvsWugxspt?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But was looking the user can resize each column as normally allows any tool like excel for example.That is, you can make larger or smaller the width of each column that appears in the grid from a report . The user widen a column and shrink others. Sorry , it was my fault that just explain not clear.

Comment: @user3749378 - have you actually tried the plunkr? If you hover the mouse between columns you will see a ◄► mouse cursor and then you can resize the columns.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not realize that this plugin could be use for our   requirements of resizing just as we needed. I went completely unnoticed about the resize feature, sorry.

We will try and tell you , thanks for your help